# using api response data in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel

I am using a Laravel package that gets the latest exchange rates from the European Bank.

When I call

```
$lookup = new ExchangeRatesAPI();
$rsp  = $lookup->setBaseCurrency('GBP')->fetch();
```

I get

```
BenMajor\ExchangeRatesAPI\Response {#571 ▼
  -response: GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response {#566 ▶}
  -headers: array:15 [▶]
  -bodyRaw: "{"rates":{"CAD":1.7151176498,"HKD":10.279978309,"ISK":161.385391616,"PHP":66.9884943651,"DKK":8.8082944311,"HUF":388.9989154524,"CZK":29.9559107842,"GBP":1.0,"R ▶"
  -body: {#554 ▶}
  -statusCode: 200
  -timestamp: "2020-01-03T09:22:49+00:00"
  -baseCurrency: "GBP"
  -rates: {#569 ▼
    +"CAD": 1.7151176498
    +"HKD": 10.279978309
    +"ISK": 161.385391616
    +"PHP": 66.9884943651
    +"DKK": 8.8082944311
    +"HUF": 388.9989154524
    +"CZK": 29.9559107842
    +"GBP": 1.0
    +"RON": 5.638232659
    +"SEK": 12.3459235158
    +"IDR": 18320.507379639
    +"INR": 94.1982600085
    +"BRL": 5.289527043
    +"RUB": 81.564224077
    +"HRK": 8.7759937756
    +"JPY": 143.5257226388
    +"THB": 39.7757815816
    +"CHF": 1.2808270854
    +"EUR": 1.1788560381
    +"MYR": 5.3949167728
    +"BGN": 2.3056066393
    +"TRY": 7.8628518885
    +"CNY": 9.1887112746
    +"NOK": 11.6008864997
    +"NZD": 1.9708115245
    +"ZAR": 18.5665110577
    +"USD": 1.3194935634
    +"MXN": 24.9190125902
    +"SGD": 1.7781864479
    +"AUD": 1.8868769746
    +"ILS": 4.5609940114
    +"KRW": 1530.4380629038
    +"PLN": 5.0153251285
  }
}
```

All of which is fine.

However what I want to do is to get hold the rates themselves and present them in a simple table.

I have tried to json_decode $rsp and I get

> json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$lookup = new ExchangeRatesAPI();
$rsp  = $lookup->setBaseCurrency('GBP')->fetch();
dd(json_decode($rsp->getRates());
```

method getRates() will return rates as array - more on [ExchangeRatesAPI - response](https://github.com/benmajor/ExchangeRatesAPI#response-reference)

Comment: If I use $rsp  = $lookup->setBaseCurrency('GBP')->getRates(); I get an empty variable. If I add fetch at the end it gives an error.

Comment: Got it. I chained the getRates rather than realising it was an internal function, so if I add $rt = $rsp->getRates(); I get the array.

Comment: Just for clarity here is what works:

$lookup = new ExchangeRatesAPI();
$rsp  = $lookup->setBaseCurrency('GBP')->fetch();
$rt = $rsp->getRates();
dd($rt);

Thanks everyone

Answer (score 1):

Already `$rsp` contains an object. So you cant decode it again.
For getting the rates

```
dd($rsp->rates);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do:

```
$rates = $rsp->getRates();
```

And a loop through the rates.

Source of *BenMajor\ExchangeRatesAPI\Response*: https://github.com/benmajor/ExchangeRatesAPI/blob/master/src/Response.php